# Why is there a second entry when running 'finger' in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, finger

When I run `finger` on OS X, I see two entries:

```
Login   Name          TTY  Idle  Login  Time   Office  Phone
user    user         *con    2d  Thu    15:59
user    user          s00        Sat    23:58
```

I have one terminal open, so it's fairly obvious where the second entry comes from.  But can anyone tell me anything about why the first entry is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*con is the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I had my suspicions, but it's nice to be sure!

Comment: Short for console if it's any help.

Answer (score 1):

Spiff is right, but I don't have the reputation to vote him up yet.. Put another way, your Terminal session is one process, and your Window Manager process (the one you logged into when you started the machine) is the other. Hence two entries.